# Metamask signature request on opensea

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, ethers.js, opensea

Can you please explain why we need to sign the message when connecting the wallet on opensea? Why is it so necessary and what? I tried to sign and reject it, but I didn't see any difference on UI. What does the nonce mean specifically in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to sign the message when connecting the wallet on OpenSea because you need to give OpenSea permission to view your account balance, wallet address, and request transaction approval. Also, a user with a signed message means the user owns the account. The nonce represents how many times the user has logged in and is included in the signed message for the server in OpenSea for verification purposes.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer @Yongijan P. ! You have covered all aspects of my question, though I'd like to clarify one moment about nonce. Does it contain only the amount of logging or smth else? If I got it right from the image of my question, a nonce is a hash of the number of logging, is it right?